# Rebase shows as Detached in Branch field

Tags: git, visual-studio, git-bash, rebase

I am pretty new to Git. I was actually trying to rebase my child branch onto the parent (develop) branch.

What I did is using Git bash

```
> git checkout develop  //checkout to my parent branch
> git pull   //took all the changes
> git rebase develop
```

Then it show some conflic message and in Visual Studio Git Changes tool box it shows like this
[image]

I didnt understand what to do next.. Push/Pull nothing is enabled. Please help

Comment: You have to finish the rebase process. Resolve any conflicts, commit the results, and continue to the rest of the rebase.

Comment: After fixing the conflicts, `git add` the fixed files, then run `git rebase --continue`.

Answer (score 3):

Rebase works by copying existing commits to new-and-improved commits.  Once all the old (and lousy?) commits have been successfully copied to new, supposedly-improved commits, rebase will switch the *branch name* around so that it locates the new commits, rather than the old commits.

Because this switching-around happens at the *end* of the process—not the middle—Git has a bit of a problem: new commits get added to whichever branch you're "on" (where being "on branch X" means that running `git status` makes it say `on branch X`).  You can't be "on" the branch you're rebasing, and you can't be "on" any other branch either.  So `git rebase` starts by putting you into Git's *detached HEAD* mode, where you are not on *any* branch.

You can in fact use Git without having any branches at all.  Git isn't really about branches, and isn't really about files either: Git is really all about *commits*.  All you need to use Git is some set of commits.  But Git *finds* commits by their big ugly random-looking hash IDs, which humans are very bad at.  So we use *branch names* that make Git store the hash IDs for us, so that we don't have to memorize them.  That's all fine and good in normal operation, but during rebase, Git takes you "off-branch" so as to perform the rebase copying process, leaving you in this weird, not-very-usable-by-humans mode.<sup>1</sup>

**If the rebase works all on its own,** Git exits the detached-HEAD mode all on its own and does the branch-name-changing trick, so that now your branch name finds the new-and-improved commits, leaving the old-and-lousy commits abandoned.<sup>2</sup>  In that case there's nothing special to do.  But, as you have just seen, **sometimes the rebase cannot finish on its own**, and in that case you must help Git to finish the rebase.

To understand *how* to help Git finish the rebase, you should begin by understanding how to help Git finish a conflicted merge.  So look into that next, keeping in mind that `git rebase` copies each commit using `git cherry-pick`.<sup>3</sup>  There's one cherry-pick operation for *each commit to be copied*, and *each* cherry-pick *can* have a merge conflict.  So if you're rebasing 100 commits, you may have to stop and fix problems 100 times!  But in practice we don't normally rebase that many commits *and* most of them don't have conflicts: we'll more typically see 1 or 2 or 3 commits have copying conflicts when rebasing 20 or 30 commits.

Once you've resolved the cherry-pick merge conflict—which you do in the same way you resolve *any* merge conflict—you will run `git rebase --continue` to tell Git to store, in the new commit, the files you've said hold the correct result.<sup>4</sup>  Git will do that and then go on to copy the next commit in the sequence.  If that succeeds, Git will go on to do the commit after that, and so on, until it has copied all the commits in the sequence.  Once Git has copied the *last* commit in the sequence, it will finish the rebase and put you back "on" the branch, which will now locate the most recent of the new-and-improved copies.

You will need to repeat this `git rebase --continue` action after resolving each conflicting cherry-pick.  Should you decide, at any point, that the rebase is not going well, you can use `git rebase --abort` to stop the copying process and go back to the original (old and lousy) commits as found by the original branch name, but of course then you must decide what you're going to do instead of this rebase that you just aborted.

---

<sup>1</sup>One place where it *is* usable by humans is when checking out any particularly interesting historical commit.  For instance, you can use `git log` to find some commit hash ID that you think is particularly interesting, then check out this commit by hash ID.  This puts you in the same "detached HEAD" mode.  Or you can use a *tag*, like `v2.3`, to check out some particular release version.  As with a hash ID, this puts you in "detached HEAD" mode, using that particular release version.

To get back to the normal "on a branch" mode, you just check out or switch to a branch name.

<sup>2</sup>These abandoned commits *might* be findable by some *other* branch name, or perhaps a tag name or whatever.  In that case, they remain healthy.  If they are abandoned long enough and have *no* name to find them, they will wither away and die—at least in a regular *Git* repository.  Some Git-repository-software, such as the stuff used on GitHub, make sure to feed-and-water  even the abandoned commits so that they live forever.

<sup>3</sup>In older versions of Git, `git rebase` may sometimes use something other than a literal `git cherry-pick` operation, but the effect is mostly the same, and the way you work with the merge conflict and continue the rebase remains the same.  So you can think of this as a cherry-pick, even in these older versions of Git that sometimes use a different internal command.

<sup>4</sup>As with *any* merge operation, if Git stops for any reason—usually, because of a conflict—you gain absolute control.  *You* now *totally control* what is going to go into the new commit snapshot.  It's up to you to come up with the *correct set of files*, because Git will absolutely, totally, 100% believe that you did so.  (If you come up with the wrong resolution, it's the same as if you commit a bug: you'll just have to fix it later.  You can always add another commit, or even do another rebase.  In fact, it's not just "the same as if" you commit a bug, it *is* that you're committing a bug.  There's no real difference.)